# Passing arguments to fsolve

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I'm solving a nonlinear equation with many constants.
I created a function for solving like:

```
def terminalV(Vt, data):
    from numpy import sqrt
    ro_p, ro, D_p, mi, g = (i for i in data)
    y = sqrt((4*g*(ro_p - ro)*D_p)/(3*C_d(Re(data, Vt))*ro)) - Vt
    return y
```

Then I want to do:

```
data = (1800, 994.6, 0.208e-3, 8.931e-4, 9.80665)
Vt0 = 1
Vt = fsolve(terminalV, Vt0, args=data)
```

But `fsolve` is unpacking `data` and passing too many arguments to `terminalV` function, so I get:

> TypeError: terminalV() takes exactly 2 arguments (6 given)

So, my question can I somehow pass a tuple to the function called by `fsolve()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use an asterisk to tell your function to repack the tuple. The standard way to pass arguments as a tuple is the following:

```
from numpy import sqrt   # leave this outside the function
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#  here it is     V
def terminalV(Vt, *data):
    ro_p, ro, D_p, mi, g = data   # automatic unpacking, no need for the 'i for i'
    return sqrt((4*g*(ro_p - ro)*D_p)/(3*C_d(Re(data, Vt))*ro)) - Vt

data = (1800, 994.6, 0.208e-3, 8.931e-4, 9.80665)
Vt0 = 1
Vt = fsolve(terminalV, Vt0, args=data)
```

Without `fsolve`, i.e., if you just want to call `terminalV` on its own, for example if you want to see its value at `Vt0`, then you must unpack `data` with a star:

```
data = (1800, 994.6, 0.208e-3, 8.931e-4, 9.80665)
Vt0 = 1
terminalV(Vt0, *data)
```

Or pass the values individually:

```
terminalV(Vt0, 1800, 994.6, 0.208e-3, 8.931e-4, 9.80665)
```

Comment: Automatic unpacking is very convenient. Also  using asterisk is great and solves my problem. Thank You very much

Comment: How I can give to broyden1 function extra arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
Vt = fsolve(terminalV, Vt0, args=[data])
```

Comment: yes, that helped, tahnk You. But i had to add `data[0]` in: `ro_p, ro, D_p, mi, g = (i for i in data)`  can i avoid it ?

Comment: The problem here is that you're just adding another layer of container, so you're passing a list with a tuple inside it, instead of using the proper unpacking syntax.  @user2965967, Please see my answer for a better explanation.