# Python fsolve ValueError

Tags: python, scipy

Why does the following code return a ValueError?

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def f(p,a=0):
    x,y = p
    return (np.dot(x,y)-a,np.outer(x,y)-np.ones((3,3)),x+y-np.array([1,2,3]))

x,y = fsolve(f,(np.ones(3),np.ones(3)),9)


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. This message may appear without the existing of a sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app)

Comment: The function itself does not cause any problems, I just don't understand why fsolve does not work.

Comment: The argument `p` in the function and the initial guess must be a single array, not a tuple of two arrays

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't fail with that error when I try it on my box (although it does fail!).  Can you specify python version, numpy and scipy versions and the full error stack trace, please?

Comment: I think you ***might*** be suffering the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843116/passing-arguments-to-fsolve) - i.e. you think you are passing a tuple of two lists (`np.ones(3)`) to your function but they're being unpacked "under the covers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is that your function `f` does not satisfy the criteria required for `fsolve` to work.  These criteria are described [in the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) - although arguably not very clearly.

The particular things that you need to be aware of are:

1. the input to the function that will be solved for must be an n-dimensional vector (referred to in the docs as *ndarray*), such that the value of `x` you want is the solution to `f(x, *args) = 0`.
2. the output of `f` must be the same *shape* as the `x` input to `f`.

Currently, your function takes a 2 member `tuple` of `1x3-arrays` (in `p`) and a fixed scalar offset (in `a`).  It returns a 3 member `tuple` of types (`scalar`,`3x3 array`, `1x3 array`)

As you can see, neither condition 1 nor 2 is met.

It is hard to advise you on exactly how to fix this without being exactly sure of the equation you are trying to solve.  It seems you are trying to solve some particular equation `f(x,y,a) = 0` for `x` and `y` with `x0 = (1,1,1)` and `y0 = (1,1,1)` and `a = 9` as a fixed value.  You ***might*** be able to do this by passing in `x` and `y` concatenated (e.g. pass in `p0 = (1,1,1,1,1,1)` and in the function use `x=p[:3]` and `y = p[3:]` but then you must modify your function to output x and y concatenated into a 6-dimensional vector similarly.  This depends on the exact function your are solving for and I can't work this out from the output of your existing `f` (i.e based on a dot product, outer product and sum based tuple).

**Note** that arguments that you don't pass in the vector (e.g. `a` in your case) will be treated as fixed values and won't be varied as part of the optimisation or returned as part of any solution.

---

## Note for those who like the full story...

[As the docs say:](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)

> `fsolve` is a wrapper around MINPACK’s hybrd and hybrj algorithms.

If we look at the [MINPACK hybrd documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrd.html), the conditions for the input and output vectors are more clearly stated.  See the relevant bits below (I've cut some stuff out for clarity - indicated with ... - and added the comment to show that the input and output must be the same shape - indicated with <--)

> 1 Purpose.
>
> The purpose of HYBRD is to find a zero of a system of N non-
>      linear functions in N variables by a modification of the Powell
>      hybrid method.  The user must provide a subroutine which calcu-
>      lates the functions.  The Jacobian is then calculated by a for-
>      ward-difference approximation.
>
> 2 Subroutine and type statements.
>
> ```
>    SUBROUTINE HYBRD(FCN,N,X, ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `FCN` is the name of the user-supplied subroutine which calculates
>        the functions.  FCN must be declared in an EXTERNAL statement
>        in the user calling program, and should be written as follows.
>
> ```
>  SUBROUTINE FCN(N,X,FVEC,IFLAG)
>  INTEGER N,IFLAG
>  DOUBLE PRECISION X(N),FVEC(N)  <-- input X is an array length N, so is output FVEC
>  ----------
>  CALCULATE THE FUNCTIONS AT X AND
>  RETURN THIS VECTOR IN FVEC.
>  ----------
>  RETURN
>  END
> ```
>
> `N` is a positive integer input variable set to the number of
>        functions and variables.
>
> `X` is an array of length N.  On input X must contain an initial
>        estimate of the solution vector.  On output X contains the
>        final estimate of the solution vector.