# Passing extra arguments to broyden1

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

Im trying to execute scipy [broyden1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.broyden1.html) function with extra parameters (called "data" in the example), here is the code:

```
data = [radar_wavelen, satpos, satvel, ellipsoid_semimajor_axis, ellipsoid_semiminor_axis, srange]
target_xyz = broyden1(Pixlinexyx_2Bsolved, start_xyz, args=data)

def Pixlinexyx_2Bsolved(target, *data):
    radar_wavelen, satpos, satvel, ellipsoid_semimajor_axis, ellipsoid_semiminor_axis, srange = data

    print target
    print radar_wavelen, satpos, satvel, ellipsoid_semimajor_axis, ellipsoid_semiminor_axis, srange
```

**Pixlinexyx_2Bsolved** is the function whose root I want to find.

**start_xyz** is initial guess of the solution:

```
start_xyz = [4543557.208584103, 1097477.4119051248, 4176990.636060918]
```

And **data** is this list containing a lot of numbers, that will be used inside the **Pixlinexyx_2Bsolved** function:

```
data = [0.056666, [5147114.2523595653, 1584731.770061729, 4715875.3525346108], [5162.8213179936156, -365.24378919717839, -5497.6237250296626], 6378144.0430000005, 6356758.789000001, 850681.12442702544]
```

When I call the function broyden1 (as in the second line of example code) I get the next error:

```
target_xyz = broyden1(Pixlinexyx_2Bsolved, start_xyz, args=data)
  File "<string>", line 5, in broyden1
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Now, seeing the documentation of [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), it seems to be able to get extra args in the callable func... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843116/passing-arguments-to-fsolve) is a similar question as mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar question at scipy's [issue-tracker](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3562) including a solution using python's [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)-module (here: [PEP 309 -- Partial Function Application](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/)
).

Small example based on the above link and the original problem from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.nonlin.html#examples):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

""" No external data """
def F(x):
   return np.cos(x) + x[::-1] - [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = scipy.optimize.broyden1(F, [1,1,1,1], f_tol=1e-14)
print(x)

""" External data """
from functools import partial
def G(data, x):
    return np.cos(x) + x[::-1] - data
data = [1,2,3,4]
G_partial = partial(G, data)
x = scipy.optimize.broyden1(G_partial, [1,1,1,1], f_tol=1e-14)
print(x)
```

#### Out

```
[ 4.04674914  3.91158389  2.71791677  1.61756251]
[ 4.04674914  3.91158389  2.71791677  1.61756251]
```