# Object as arguments to fsolve

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve what is effectively a non-linear equation, containing a spline object. Since I want to do this many times with different data I don't want to create a new function for each data set, but create only one function and pass the spline on as an argument.

The data are in reality experimental data to which I fit a spline and the equation I'm trying to solve is rather complicated, but to illustrate my problem I'm using a simple sine function in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def equation(x0,func):
    return ( interpolate.splev(x0,func) - 1 )

x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,1)
y = np.sin(x)
yy = interpolate.splrep(x,y)

x0 = 3
root = fsolve(equation,x0,yy)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: equation() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

How can I do this? Any suggestion? Maybe it cant be done this way, and if so, is there another solution?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843116/passing-arguments-to-fsolve

Comment: That third argument to `fsolve` is supposed to be a tuple (read the docs).  Do you want `yy` to interpreted as such?  Or maybe you should use `args=(yy,)`.

Comment: Here's another answer to a question about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388319/passing-args-in-scipy-optimize-minimize-objective-function-getting-error-on-nu/31388592#31388592.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks!